# How do I use the damage workspace on 4e character sheets?

Tags: dnd-4e

Just looking for clarification on this. I'm DM and all my player's just leveled up so I'm making sure they did this properly. When using the character sheet's damage workspace, is this just for basic attacks? Or does the same formula apply to powers as well? Say a power does 1d12 + STR mod damage. Is it just the flat ability mod? Or are the weapon proficiency, feats, and enhancements added to this as well?

Comment: Welcome. I've edited the title and the tags to be a bit more appropriate to your question. Check out our [FAQ].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This entirely depends partly on the keyword of the power, and partly what the power says.

Most weapon attack powers take the following form:

> **target:** stat vs def
>
> **hit:** 1[W] + stat

This is your set of clues as to what to add to the following for the to-hit

```
 +stat + 1/2 level + weapon prof + enhancement bonus + feat mods + other mods
```

And the following for damage

```
 weapon damage die + stat + feat mods + enhancement bonus + other damage mods
```

Powers with the implement keyword work the same way with the following exceptions:

- You don't get the weapon proficiency bonus for to-hit
- You don't get the weapon damage die and instead the power will indicate the damage die if there is one (if there is not, then the power does not have a damage roll by default).

To answer your specific questions:

- You should work out and precalculate the damage for *every power*. It will likely be mostly the same, but it helps to have it indicated for every one, in case there are differences (encounter powers often are 2[W], some at-wills will add a second stat etc, or don't add a stat to damage at all).
- For powers that say 1[W] + str that indicates that that you add your str mod, not str + 1/2 level to damage. "Str" and "Str mod" are often used interchangeably. They both mean the modifier. If the score is to be used the text will specify str score.
- Weapon proficiency is not added to damage
- Feats that apply to "attack rolls" do not apply to damage rolls (expertise feats are a biggie, but look for this phrasing)
- Feats that apply to "damage done" or "damage rolls" apply to damage
- Enhancement bonuses are added to both weapon and implement damage expressions.

Hope this helps and please feel free to ask if you have any other questions.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that they'll use "Str" and "Str mod" interchangeably; they *always* mean to use the modifier unless they use the word "score" too.